# Difference between definer 'root@%' and definer 'root@localhost' in mysql triggers?

Tags: mysql

I need to clarify something about mysql definer root@% and root@localhost

when i export database from a server then import again with another db name it was changes from root@% to root@localhost. then my trigger won't work.after change localhost into %,it was working fine.

Comment: This refers to the host you are logging from. `@%` means, for this user, from any host, whereas `@localhost` means for this user, only if they login from 'localhost'.